# Java jnlp force to run with 32bits version

Tags: java, jvm, jnlp

Our java client application needs java of 32bits because of used dlls. There is no option for 64bits jvm. But our clients, 300+ users, need 64bits jvm installed on their computers because another application needs 64bits jvm on their operationg systems (windows). As a result they have to install both 32 and 64 bits jvm. When clicking our jnlp, it runs automatically with 64 bits jvm and our program fails. Is there any option/syntax in the jnlp file to force a specific jvm? I do not mean the libraries or nativelibs, i mean when clicking our jnlp file, the 32bits jvm should start.

It is not possible/feasible to edit environment path variables on 300 clients, we need a global solution, just by editing our jnlp file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can force javaws to use the 32-bit JRE by specifying an invalid j2se version for 64-bit (1.0.0 in the sample below, note that j2se version needs to be specified inside the arch-specific resources section for it to work).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///c:/jnlp" href="demo.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Demo</title>  
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security> 
    <resources>
        <jar href="demo.jar" />
    </resources>
    <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
        <j2se version="1.0.0"/>
    </resources>    
    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <j2se version="1.8+"/>
        <jar href="win32/swt.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="package.to.MainClass"/>
</jnlp>
```

Note that this is a bit of a "dirty hack" and may well stop working with a future release.